# save figures in matlab during loop

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am interested if it is possible to save figures which occurs during the loop.
For example, I have created some random matrix,

```
 r=rand(8,5)


r =

0.8147    0.9575    0.4218    0.6787    0.2769
0.9058    0.9649    0.9157    0.7577    0.0462
0.1270    0.1576    0.7922    0.7431    0.0971
0.9134    0.9706    0.9595    0.3922    0.8235
0.6324    0.9572    0.6557    0.6555    0.6948
0.0975    0.4854    0.0357    0.1712    0.3171
0.2785    0.8003    0.8491    0.7060    0.9502
0.5469    0.1419    0.9340    0.0318    0.0344
```

now if I use  this  line

```
plot(r(1,:))
```

I get following figure

[image]

My question is, if I use loop

```
for i=1:8
   plot(r(i,:))
end
```

it shows me one graph of  row, but it odes not do cycle, so can I show all  8  figures  step by step in matlab. For exmaple interval may be 10 seconds, for this as I know function `movie` is used, also `getframe`, or could I save figures in loop?
Also, I know that imsave or something like this. I think better would be  save somewhere, so if I can use  like this

```
imsave(plot(r(i,:))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `getframe` to capture the content of the current figure handle

```
fh = figure
% ...
for ii = 1:8
    figure( fh ); % focus on figure
    plot( r(ii,:) );
    frm = getframe( fh );
    % save as png image
    imwrite( frm.cdata, sprintf( 'current_frame_%02d.png', ii ) );
end
```

PS
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab)

Comment: and where it  writes?in folder in which this m file is right?

Comment: It's writes to the output of `pwd`.

Comment: @dato it writes the png images to your current working directory.

Comment: thanks friends,it was really helpful for me,now i am testing it

Comment: it left 1 minute my friend,this site  requires  some minute before  accept

Answer (score 1):

I think that there are multiple solutions to your problem:

- Use the `pause` function, which can make a pause so that you can look at your figure.
- Print each image in a new figure. To achieve this, just put `figure(i)` in your `for` loop.
- Or save the image using the `print` function.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to display all the plots by using a loop, you can do the following:

```
for ii=1:8
    figure();
    plot(r(ii,:));
end
```